# concat variable to a R.raw.(VARIABLEHERE)

Tags: java, android, concatenation

How can i concat a variable to obtain a R.x.x like

String marca = htc;

R.id.marca

I think is a stupid ask..

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot di that. Java is not allowing you to do this sort of coding, like in PHP or JavaScript...

---

Try searching about reflection... Maybe it is possible anyway.

Comment: I think this is not posible with reflection...But thanks every way